# kubernetes pod status always "pending"

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the Fedora getting started guide (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_ansible_config.md) and trying to run the pod `fedoraapache`. But `kubectl` always shows `fedoraapache` as pending:

```
POD                 IP                  CONTAINER(S)        IMAGE(S)            HOST                              LABELS              STATUS
fedoraapache                            fedoraapache        fedora/apache       192.168.226.144/192.168.226.144   name=fedoraapache   Pending
```

Since it is pending, I cannot run `kubectl log pod fedoraapache`. So,
I instead run `kubectl describe pod fedoraapache`, which shows the following errors:

```
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:05 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:05 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   created     Created with docker id d4877bdffd4f2a13a17d4cc93c27c1c93d5494807b39ee8a823f5d9350e404d4
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:05 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:05 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}                       failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: API error (500): Cannot start container d4877bdffd4f2a13a17d4cc93c27c1c93d5494807b39ee8a823f5d9350e404d4:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   created Created with docker id 1c32b4c6e1aad0e575f6a155aebefcd5dd96857b12c47a63bfd8562fba961747
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   failed  Failed to start with docker id 1c32b4c6e1aad0e575f6a155aebefcd5dd96857b12c47a63bfd8562fba961747 with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 1c32b4c6e1aad0e575f6a155aebefcd5dd96857b12c47a63bfd8562fba961747:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:15 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}       failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: API error (500): Cannot start container 1c32b4c6e1aad0e575f6a155aebefcd5dd96857b12c47a63bfd8562fba961747:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}       failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: API error (500): Cannot start container 8b117ee5c6bf13f0e97b895c367ce903e2a9efbd046a663c419c389d9953c55e:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   created Created with docker id 8b117ee5c6bf13f0e97b895c367ce903e2a9efbd046a663c419c389d9953c55e
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:25 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   failed  Failed to start with docker id 8b117ee5c6bf13f0e97b895c367ce903e2a9efbd046a663c419c389d9953c55e with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 8b117ee5c6bf13f0e97b895c367ce903e2a9efbd046a663c419c389d9953c55e:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   failed  Failed to start with docker id 4b463040842b6a45db2ab154652fd2a27550dbd2e1a897c98473cd0b66d2d614 with error: API error (500): Cannot start container 4b463040842b6a45db2ab154652fd2a27550dbd2e1a897c98473cd0b66d2d614:  (exit status 1)

  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   created     Created with docker id 4b463040842b6a45db2ab154652fd2a27550dbd2e1a897c98473cd0b66d2d614
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 21:42:35 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800 109 {kubelet 192.168.226.144}   implicitly required container POD   pulled      Successfully pulled image "kubernetes/pause:latest"
  Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800   Fri, 20 Mar 2015 22:00:35 +0800 1   {kubelet 192.168.226.144}                       failedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: API error (500): Cannot start container 4b463040842b6a45db2ab154652fd2a27550dbd2e1a897c98473cd0b66d2d614:  (exit status 1)
```

Comment: I've been playing with Container Engine as well and have had problems today - although without exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: But when I log into that minion machine, I actually can start containers with those images manually. I think this is kubernates' problem.

Comment: Can you ssh into the host machine and see if /var/log/kubelet.log has any more info on why it couldn't start those containers?

Comment: I don't have such file /var/log/lubelet.log in the host machine.

Comment: Hmmm. Those events look like kubelet is running okay, but failed to start a few containers. If there is not /var/log/kubelet.log, do you have any interesting output in /var/log/docker.log from around that time? Or maybe your logs are stored somewhere other than /var/log/?

Comment: Have you tried to find failing container ID using `docker ps -a` and then `docker logs <<container ID>>`? Is it likely that your container starts and exits(1) quickly?

Comment: Have you been able to start your docker container locally?

Answer (score 4):

There are several reasons container can fail to start:

- the container command itself fails and exits -> check your docker image and start up script to make sure it works. 
  Use 
  `sudo docker ps -a` to find the offending container and 
  `sudo docker logs <container>` to check for failure inside the container
- a dependency is not there: that happens for example when one tries to mount a volume that is not present, for example *Secrets* that are not created yet. 
  --> make sure the dependent volumes are created.

Answer (score 2):

Kubelet is unable to start the container we use for holding the network namespace. Some things to try are:

Can you manually pull and run gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0? (This is the image used for the network namespace container at head right now.)

As mentioned already, /var/log/kubelet.log should have more detail; but log location is distro-dependent, so check https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/wiki/Debugging-FAQ#checking-logs.

Answer (score 1):

Step one is to describe the pod and see the problems:

```
 $ kubectl describe pod <pod Name>
```

or

If you use master node, then you can configure the master node to run pods with:

```
$ kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if is Kubelet is running on your machine. I came across this problem one time and discovered that Kubelet was not running, which explains why the pod status was stuck in "pending". Kubelet runs as a systemd service in my environment, so if that is also the case for you then the following command will help you check its status:

```
systemctl status kubelet
```